# How to use .assign with with .where() for "condition, true, false" like in numpy.where()?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I have a dataframe df:

```
# %%
import pandas as pd
# %%
values = [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3), ("d", 4), ("a", 4), ("b", 6), ("c", 7), ("d", 8)]
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=["name", "value"])
# %%
```

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 4 |
| a | 4 |
| b | 6 |
| c | 7 |
| d | 8 |

I want to:

1. add a new column named "kpi"
2. in a function chaining pipeline with `.assign`
3. without `numpy`
4. without `.apply` (= loops = super slow = anti pattern)
5. without `.query` (= no auto complete, no auto formatting, no linting, no syntax highlighting = anti pattern for me)
6. with the following condition:

> if (name.in("a", "b")) & (value % 2 == 0)) then (value / 5 * 100) else (value / 2)

So the end result should look like:

| name | value | kpi |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 0.5 |
| b | 2 | 40 |
| c | 3 | 1.5 |
| d | 4 | 2 |
| a | 4 | 80 |
| b | 6 | 120 |
| c | 7 | 3.5 |
| d | 8 | 4 |

So I need a condition and then a way to set the new value depending on the if/else = a ternary operator.

But pandas.where() has no else branch I can set?

Comment: why without numpy?

Comment: SO is not a place to get help with your homework

Comment: @gtomer this is not a homework task but a question to replace numpy.where() with a "pure" pandas ternary function. Couldn't find a solution in the docs or on SO so I'm asking.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df = df.assign(kpi = df['value'].div(5).mul(100).where(df['name'].isin(['a','b']) & 
                                                       (df['value'] % 2 == 0), 
                      df['value'].div(2)))
print (df)
  name  value    kpi
0    a      1    0.5
1    b      2   40.0
2    c      3    1.5
3    d      4    2.0
4    a      4   80.0
5    b      6  120.0
6    c      7    3.5
7    d      8    4.0
```

Solution for chaining with `lambda`:

```
df = df.assign(kpi = lambda x: x['value'].div(5).mul(100).where(x['name'].isin(['a','b']) &
                                                                (x['value'] % 2 == 0), 
                               x['value'].div(2)))
print (df)
  name  value    kpi
0    a      1    0.5
1    b      2   40.0
2    c      3    1.5
3    d      4    2.0
4    a      4   80.0
5    b      6  120.0
6    c      7    3.5
7    d      8    4.0
```

Comment: FWIW, nothing to do with me

Comment: @mozway - I dont use script for check DV, so no idea.

Comment: Neither do I. I'm just telling you since I don't want you to believe I DV you out of retaliation. I'm not playing this game.

Answer (score 3):

Without [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) you can use [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) with a callable and [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html), [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
out = d.assign(kpi=lambda d: d['value'].div(5).mul(100)
                             .where(  d['name'].isin(['a', 'b'])
                                    & d['value'].mod(2).eq(0),
                                    d['value'].div(2))
              )
```

Output:

```
  name  value    kpi
0    a      1    0.5
1    b      2   40.0
2    c      3    1.5
3    d      4    2.0
4    a      4   80.0
5    b      6  120.0
6    c      7    3.5
7    d      8    4.0
```

I personally prefer the [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) variant:

```
out = d.assign(kpi=lambda d: np.where(  d['name'].isin(['a', 'b'])
                                      & d['value'].mod(2).eq(0),
                                      d['value'].div(5).mul(100),
                                      d['value'].div(2)))
```

##### assigning yes/no

It's possible if you craft a Series to broadcast the string:

```
out = d.assign(kpi=lambda d: pd.Series('yes', index=d.index)
                               .where(  d['name'].isin(['a', 'b'])
                                      & d['value'].mod(2).eq(0),
                                      'no')
              )
```

But I really don't find it elegant. Better use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
out = d.assign(kpi=lambda d: np.where(  d['name'].isin(['a', 'b']),
                                      & d['value'].mod(2).eq(0),
                                      'yes', 'no')
              )
```

Output:

```
  name  value  kpi
0    a      1   no
1    b      2  yes
2    c      3   no
3    d      4   no
4    a      4  yes
5    b      6  yes
6    c      7   no
7    d      8   no
```

Comment: Thank you. How would that code change if the else branch was `pd.NA` (or some string value and not a calculation on column `value`) instead of `value / 2`?

Comment: Then don't provide an else, by default this will set a NaN

Comment: Thanks. If both `if` and `else` branch values are strings, is there a way to do so? `d['value'].div(5).mul(100)` is fine for numeric formulas but if I wanted `if cond then "yes" else "false"` I don't see a way to set the `if cond then "yes"` value?

Comment: You can craft a Series of all "yes": `pd.Series('yes', index=df.index).where(...)` but I wouldn't do that. `np.where` is more appropriate.